# pass cllocation to tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cllocation

I’m trying app that display distance between user location and target location. I intend to get user location didUpdateToLocation method and store in array. Then, put it in table view delegate “cellForRowAtIndexPath” to calculate distance and show in table cell. However, It doesn’t work. Please see my code as below. Can anybody help?

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;

NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (locationAge > 5.0) return;

if (currentLocation == nil || currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy >   newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {

self.currentLocation = newLocation;
// locationMeasurements is NSMutableArray to store currentLocation (CLLocation) information.

[locationMeasurements addObject:currentLocation];

[self.tableView reloadData];          
       }
    }
}


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



   CLLocation *location = [locationMeasurements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}
```

It crash and tell me nothing in array at console (see below). However, I NSLog this array in 'didUpdateToLocation' and it can show it correctly.

```
**** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'*
```

Then, I try to NSLog locationMeasurements (array) in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSLog(@"locationMeasurements ===%@",[locationMeasurements description]);
```

It display blank information in few statements, and then display correct information later. See below.

```
locationMeasurements ===(
)
locationMeasurements ===(
)
locationMeasurements ===(
)
locationMeasurements ===(
)
locationMeasurements ===(
    "<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) "
)
locationMeasurements ===(
    "<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) "
)
locationMeasurements ===(
    "<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) "
)
locationMeasurements ===(
     "<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) "
)
```

Can anybody give me some advice? What should I do?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you're trying to read location measurements that don't exist.  It's an error to fetch a value from an array from a position in the array that doesn't correspond to a value.

Generally if you are using an array of data to populate a `UITableView` (which is common), the number of rows in the table should match the size of the array:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
            numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [self.locationMeasurements count];
}
```

If you do that, your table view should update with a new row each time you add a `CLLocation` to your measurements array.

Rather than reloading the entire table each time you add a measurement, you could also just add the new row, which is easy, since you're always appending. It also allows you to animate the added row.  Replace

```
[locationMeasurements addObject:currentLocation];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

with

```
[locationMeasurements addObject:currentLocation];
NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([locationMeasurements count] - 1)
                                          inSection:0];
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:newPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```